# MediaWiki Simple Syntax for Cross Reference of Figures

Tags: images, mediawiki, markup

I would like to reference Figures in my wiki, much like you can in LaTeX. For example, say: "As you can see in Figure 3, mediawiki is awesome".

I found the [CrossReference extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aCrossReference) which does what I want, however, the HTML markup for it is too verbose and does not seem to be part of the regular MediaWiki syntax.

I would like to specify a Figure id inside the `[[File:bla.jpg]]` syntax for specifying images. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I get what you are trying to do. If you want to reference objects inside a page, you can give each object an ID, and form the links so they will point to the ID you you've tagged.

Template page:

```
<div id="{{{ID|1}}}">{{{object|2}}}</div>
```

On relevant pages:

```
{{obj|cool_table|image}}

...some text...[[#cool_table|in figure 4]] ...rest of text...
```